# Android ffmpeg combine multiple command

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I know this type of question is already asked before , I have tried those , but doesn't work when it comes to these commands

I am using [this libray](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android) to execute ffmpeg command in android

I am using the following command to add an overlay over video

```
"-i", input_videopath,"-ignore_loop","0","-i",overlay_path,"-filter_complex","[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v]","-shortest","-map","[v]","-map","0:a?","-ac","2", outputpath
```

And I am using the following command to add audio in the video

```
"-i", input_videopath,"-i",audioPath,"-filter:a","atempo=2.0","-c:v","copy","-map","0:v:0","-map","1:a:0","-shortest",outputpath
```

How can I merge this two commands together ?

Answer (score 1):

Combined:

```
"-i", input_videopath,"-ignore_loop","0","-i",overlay_path,"-i",audioPath,"-filter_complex","[1][0]scale2ref[i][m];[m][i]overlay[v];[2]atempo=2.0[a]","-shortest","-map","[v]","-map","0:a?","-map","[a]","-ac","2", outputpath
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it doesn't add the audio

Comment: @MithunSarkerShuvro The audio should be added. It is making two separate audio streams just like your original commands. Need to see the complete log from the ffmpeg process to make any suggestions.